# Is it possible to make a pattern that should have a certain text on the beginning and then accept anything after the certain text

Tags: javascript, regex

I dont know if i'm just overthinking this

but i was thinking of making a pattern that should have a certain text at the beginning like for example 'EDGE' then after the certain text they can put anything like for example EDGE111-1111

or should i just make a java script that substrings the first 4 words like the snippet below

```js
        function edgevalidate(e){
            var val = e.value;
            var valSubstring = val.substring(0,5)
            if(valSubstring.toUpperCase()!='EDGE'){
                alert('First 4 letters should be EDGE');
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" value='EDGE' onkeyup='edgevalidate(this)' required/>
```

but that seems to not work because it should only show the alert message only if there is no 'EDGE' at the beginning

Comment: You can use `^EDGE.*$` Or just use `^EDGE` to match the regex. Also why don't you use `startsWith`?

Comment: You realize EDGE is a 4 letter word and you're making a substring from 0-5 so 6 letters wide? The alert will always trigger unless you have "EDGE" only, your string 0-5 will never match EDGE.

Comment: But yeah, I think you don't really need a regex for this. But if you want to, just use what @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi posted.

Comment: i did not know that until now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to test is whether your string starts with `EDGE`, you don't need regex for it. You can just call `startsWith` method on string. Check this,

```js
var arr = ["EDGE111-1111", "123EDGE111-1111", "EDGE"];

for (s of arr) {
  console.log(s + " --> " + s.startsWith("EDGE"));
}
```

A regex solution for same would be this, but regex isn't really required here,

```js
var arr = ["EDGE111-1111", "123EDGE111-1111", "EDGE"];

for (s of arr) {
  console.log(s + " --> " + /^EDGE/.test(s));
}
```